# Winsock передача прием матриц типа vector

Tags: c++, winsock

Проблема такова. Есть 2 сервера и 1 клиент. Клиент отправляет первому серверу матрицу. Он ее находит и возвращает 2 матрицы обратно. Здесь проблем нет. Но при отправке с клиента на 2 сервер 2-ух этих матриц плюс массив. Возникает проблема. Все что отправлено после массива не приходит на сервер.

Код клиента.

```
if (config[0] != "")
{
    raz.setMasLength(Files.getMasLength());
    raz.setMatrixAandMasB(Files.getMatrixA(), Files.getMasB());
    start = clock();
    1 сервер здесь все работает
    SOCKET socketConnection = NetWork.openClient(config[0], config[1], stoi(config[2]));
    NetWork.sendMasLength(socketConnection, raz.getMasLength());
    NetWork.sendMatrix(socketConnection, raz.getMasLength(), raz.getMatrixA());
    raz.setMatrixL(NetWork.recvMatrix(socketConnection, raz.getMasLength()));
    raz.setMatrixU(NetWork.recvMatrix(socketConnection, raz.getMasLength()));
    NetWork.closeSocket(socketConnection, config[0]);

    2 сервер
    SOCKET socketConnections = NetWork.openClient(config[3], config[4], stoi(config[5]));
    NetWork.sendMasLength(socketConnections, raz.getMasLength());
    //Вот тут и начинаются проблемы.
    NetWork.sendMas(socketConnections, raz.getMasLength(), raz.getMasB());
    NetWork.sendMatrix(socketConnections, raz.getMasLength(), raz.getMatrixL());
    NetWork.sendMatrix(socketConnections, raz.getMasLength(), raz.getMatrixU());
    raz.setMasX(NetWork.recvMas(socketConnections, raz.getMasLength()));
    NetWork.closeSocket(socketConnections, config[3]);

    end = clock();
    cout << "Время обработки :" << ((double)end - start) / ((double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << " секунд." << endl;

    raz.getMasX();
}
```

Код Класса работающего с сетью. Индентичен за исключение создания подключения сервер/клиент.

```
int WorkNetwork::recvMasLength(SOCKET socket)
{
int result = 0;
recv(socket, (char*)&result, sizeof(result), 0);
return result;
}

void WorkNetwork::sendMatrix(SOCKET socket, vector<vector<float>> matrix)
{
for (auto& x : matrix)
{
    send(socket, (char*)x.data(), x.size() * sizeof(float), 0);
}
}

vector<vector<float>> WorkNetwork::recvMatrix(SOCKET socket, int masLength)
{
vector<vector<float>>matrixTemp(masLength, vector<float>(masLength));
for (int i = 0; i < masLength; i++)
{
    recv(socket, (char*)matrixTemp[i].data(), sizeof(float)*masLength, 0);
}
return matrixTemp;
}

void WorkNetwork::closeConnection(SOCKET socket)
{
if (closesocket(socket) == 0)
{
    cout << "Server stoped" << endl;
}
}
```

Код 1 сервера.

```
system("cls");
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
WorkFile Files;
WorkNetwork WorkNet;
server_config = Files.ReadFromFileXml();
SOCKET socket = WorkNet.openServerConnection(server_config[0], server_config[1], server_config[2]);
masLength = WorkNet.recvMasLength(socket);
initVetor();
matrixA = WorkNet.recvMatrix(socket,masLength);
naxoshdenie_LU();
WorkNet.sendMatrix(socket, matrixL);
WorkNet.sendMatrix(socket, matrixU);
WorkNet.closeConnection(socket);
system("pause");
```

Код 2 сервера.

```
system("cls");
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
WorkFile Files;
WorkNetWork WorkNet;
server_config = Files.ReadFromFileXml();
SOCKET socket = WorkNet.openServerConnection(server_config[0], server_config[1], server_config[2]);
masLength = WorkNet.recvMasLength(socket);
initVetor();
masB = WorkNet.recvMas(socket, masLength);
matrixL = WorkNet.recvMatrix(socket, masLength);
matrixU = WorkNet.recvMatrix(socket, masLength);
naxoshdenieX();
WorkNet.sendMas(socket, masX, masLength);
WorkNet.closeConnection(socket);
system("pause");
```

Проблема заключается в следующем. При отправке матрицы скажем 200*200 все хорошо. Но при отправке матрицы 1300*1300 или 2800*2800. На второй сервер не приходит ничего кроме массива. Я подозреваю что и на клиент с первого тоже не все доходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию, recv читает "сколько может, но не больше, чем указанный размер". Поэтому, вполне может быть, что recv прочитал только пол массива.

По хорошему, нужно всегда проверять, сколько прочиталось (это и возвращает recv) и по необходимости дочитывать. Или использовать спецфлаг [MSG_WAITALL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recv).

С send такая же ситуация. send вполне может отправить два-три байта. И это нужно контролировать. На [en.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479760/c-socket-recv-and-send-all-data) есть пример.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо. Все решилось достаточно просто в своих методах recv вместо 0 поставил спецфлаг, который Вы написали. И все сразу стало работать.